# Strapi: GraphQL ctx.state.user undefined inside policies

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, strapi

I tried setting up GraphQL with strapi and policies to limit user access. Normal API call gives us user info in `ctx.state.user`, but while using GraphQL this object is undefined inside api policies. Although I am able to access `ctx.state.user` inside api controller.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * `hasViewPermissions` policy.
 */

module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  console.log(ctx.state.user);// Undefined

  await next();
};
```

**schema.graphql for api**

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
      Query: {
          posts: {
              description: 'Return a list of posts',
              policy: [
                  'hasViewPermissions',
              ],
              resolver: 'Posts.find'
          },
      }
  },
};
```

`Node Version: v11.6.0`
`Strapi: 3.0.0-alpha.24.1`

Thanks

Comment: Can you precise the all code you did please. It will help to be able to help your correctly

Comment: @JimLAURIE I haven't added any code yet. Just installed the graphQL plugin and created a new policy, and added it to schema.graphql inside api config folder. I've added the schema.graphql.

Answer (score 1):

try in your controller or revolver:

```
if (!ctx.state && ctx.request && ctx.request.header && ctx.request.header.authorization) {
            const { id } = await strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services.jwt.getToken(ctx);
            ctx.state.user = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.fetchAuthenticatedUser(id);
        }
```

*check that ctx is {context}*

look:
[Strapi: GraphQL ctx.state is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612726/strapi-graphql-ctx-state-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'plugins.users-permissions.permissions' for the policies.

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
      Query: {
          posts: {
              description: 'Return a list of posts',
              policies: [
                  'plugins.users-permissions.permissions', <---
                  'hasViewPermissions',
              ],
              resolver: 'Posts.find'
          },
      }
  },
};
```