# Strapi: GraphQL ctx.state is undefined

Tags: graphql, strapi

I have a custom controller to replace a default querie named "groupedOrders"
but when I try to test the query the response is

> **"message": "Cannot read property 'user' of undefined",**

the code in api/grouped-order/controllers/grouped-order.js is:

```
module.exports = {
    byUser: async ctx => {
        const user = ctx.state.user
        const resTypeUser = await strapi.query('tipo-usuario').find({ _id: user.tipo_usuario })
        var resGroupedOrder = { error: true }
        if (resTypeUser[0].super_admin) {
            resGroupedOrder = await strapi.query('grouped-order').find()
        } else if (resTypeUser[0].cliente) {
            resGroupedOrder = await strapi.query('grouped-order').find({ users_permissions_user: user._id })
        }

        return resGroupedOrder
    }
};
```

and the code in api/grouped-order/config/schema.graphql.js is:

```
module.exports = {
  definition: ``,
  query: ``,
  type: {},
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      groupedOrders: {
        description: "Retornar todos los pedidos dependiendo el tipo de usuario",
        resolverOf: "application::grouped-order.grouped-order.byUser",
        policies: [
            'plugins::users-permissions.permissions',
        ],
        resolver: async (obj, options, ctx) => {
          return await strapi.controllers["grouped-order"].byUser(ctx);
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
```

the test that I try to run in *http://localhost:1337/graphql* is:

```
query groupedOrders($where:JSON){
  groupedOrders(where:$where){
    createdAt
    detail
    status
  }
}
```

and the HTTP HEADERS:

```
{ 
  "Authorization": "Bearer TOKENJWT"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I just add this code on my controller:

```
if (!ctx.state && ctx.request && ctx.request.header && ctx.request.header.authorization) {
            const { id } = await strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services.jwt.getToken(ctx);
            ctx.state.user = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.fetchAuthenticatedUser(id);
        }
```

we can add the code globally, like this: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/9159#issuecomment-789484109